# I want to be select a keyword from from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe, filter

```
displaytweets = tweetsDf.select( "author", "civilEvents", "phraseList",  "locations", "bodyText").orderBy("times")
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500) 
display.display(displaytweets.toPandas())
```

The 'bodyText' column contains a Tweets... I want to be able to query my dataframe to return rows where the colomn contains a hashtag.

I have tried:

```
displaytweets[displaytweets['bodyText'].str.contains("#")]
```

and also

```
hashTags = displaytweets.bodyText.str.contains("#")
```

but i get this error:

```
  <ipython-input-20-eb0d77b3103e> in <module>()   
1 #displaytweets[displaytweets['bodyText'].str.contains("#")]       
2 hashTags = displaytweets.bodyText.str.contains("#")   
3 hashTags
```

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: Are you using spark data frame? Native pandas data frame doesn't have select and orderBy with the signature you are going with.

Comment: Yes please I am using a spark dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you converted your dataframe to `pandas` this would give you what you need:

```
hashTags = displaytweets.where(displaytweets['bodyText'].str.contains('#')).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks very much.. was really helpful

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345643) my answer?